# vim: replace 2nd column blanks with values in same column if blank

Tags: bash, unix, vim, awk, sed

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
TEST,SOMELOG
TESA,SOMELOGA
TESB
TESC
TESD,SOMELOGB
TESE
TESF
TESG,SOMELOGC
```

Need to make it look like this:

```
TEST,SOMELOG
TESA,SOMELOGA
TESB,SOMELOGB
TESC,SOMELOGB
TESD,SOMELOGB
TESE,SOMELOGC
TESF,SOMELOGC
TESG,SOMELOGC
```

Where `,SOMELOGB` and `,SOMELOGC` replaces each `/r` carriage return if 2nd column is blank.  The replace only happens if 2nd column is blank though and should replace up to the non blank row.  Would consider a bash /sed/awk or vim solution.

Comment: How long is the file, is it ok if you have a pure `bash` solution, instead of `awk`  or `sed`?

Comment: The file is about 400 lines but am interested in a bash solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

if you have `tac`, this might be the easiest

```
$ tac file | awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NF==1{$2=p} NF>1{p=$2}1' | tac
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a single awk solution (specially handy when file is huge and double `tac` is expensive):

```
awk -F, 'NF==1{a=a $0 RS; next} a!=""{gsub(RS, FS $2 RS, a); printf "%s", a; a=""} 1' file

TEST,SOMELOG
TESA,SOMELOGA
TESB,SOMELOGB
TESC,SOMELOGB
TESD,SOMELOGB
TESE,SOMELOGC
TESF,SOMELOGC
TESG,SOMELOGC
```

Comment: great answer as well

Answer (score 0):

I have just figured out a vim solution:

`:v/,/norm A,S`<kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-n</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>ZZ

Explanation:

```
: ............. command mode
: v/,/ ........ match lines that not have ','
norm .......... normal mode
A ............. append text at the end of line
, ............. literal ','
S ............. inserts the first letter to use completion after
<Ctrl-v> ...... used to insert literal keyboard shortcuts
<Ctrl-n> ...... complete with the first completion option of vim
Esc ........... used to exit insert mode
ZZ ............ fast way to save and exit an existing file
```

Some ideas I have taken from [vimgolf](http://vimgolf.com/), a site where you can post, play and discuss vim solutions to daily problems.

[image: asciicast]

Answer (score 0):

I have just done the vimgolf challenge, then found the question... I put my solution (16 keystrokes )  here:

`qq2jA,S<C-N><Esc>j.q@qZZ`

http://www.vimgolf.com/challenges/5853f052854f48716101cc70

Note that, the line above just works for the example. if the file is in same format, you can replay the macro more times after recording it.